# Doctrine 2 проблема с маппингом

Tags: php, sqlite3, doctrine2, slim

Решил использовать Doctrine 2 в своем приложении на slim 3, до этого эту ORM не использовал, так что простите если спрашиваю какую-то дичь) Собственно, сразу же столкнулся со следующей проблемой: любая попытка записать что-то в БД, оканчивается ошибкой:

Class *название класса* is not a valid entity or mapped super class.

Классы на основе которых я строил entity пробовал прописывать и руками, и генерировать с помощью vendor/bin/doctrine orm:convert-mapping но все бестолку.

Буду очень признателен если укажете на мой косяк или хотя бы намекнете куда копать.

Пардон за скудное описание, но проще показать чем описать, мой код доступен в develop ветке репозитория на гитхабе, [вот тут](https://github.com/iScepsis/magpie), в качестве БД используется sqlite, так что развернуть проект будет не долго.

Тестирую все это по роуту index.php/create-schema

Comment: Как вариант попробуйте убрать все аннотации кроме doctrine.

Comment: может composer require doctrine/annotations поможет?

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался с проблемой. Оказывается я передавал не корректные настройки в файле src/settings.php. Точнее сделал все как по документации по Slim 3, но оказывается там не все так просто) 
Подсмотрел настройки в этом репозитории https://github.com/matthewfedak/slim-3-doctrine-2 и таки смог забороть ошибку.

Comment: В чем конкретно ошибка? Дайте более развернутый ответ.

Comment: Все оказалось банально, я указал некорректный путь до файлов с классами при настройке конфигурации, у меня было что-то вроде этого: \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__ . './src/Entity/'), $isDevMode) .  Но как оказалось, путь был некорректным, и видимо мне нехватало еще пары параметров для настройки прокси классов. В общем в конце концов рабочая версия оказалось такой: \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(
        [ 'src/Entity' ],
        true,
        __DIR__.'/../var/proxies',
        null,
        false
    );